# Different definitions for averages

Tags: statistics

I am stumbling across different defintions for averages and am wondering about the justification. From statistics I remember that

$<x> = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x P(x) dx$

but here they just use a different average: (see http://www.researchgate.net/publication/5808178_Physical_origin_of_the_Gouy_phase_shift equation 2). It reminds me a lot to Quantum Mechanics, but here f is already a distribution and does not like in the Quantum case only turns into a probability distribution when being squared.

$<x> = \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x |f(x)|^2 dx}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|^2 dx}$

Is there in theory an endless amount of different averages that one can define as long as they are normalized? And what qualities would make you choose one over the other?

I guess I missed something there in stats, if someone could point me in the right direction I would be thankful.

Steffen

Answer (score 0):

Your definitions are really no different, because in quantum mechanics the probability density $P(x)$ is *defined* as the square of the wave-function, $\lvert \psi(x) \rvert^2 $ (it is in the simple cases normally considered, anyway). Using unnormalised wave-functions is just typical of the ad-hoc way physicists tend to set these things up, so they can speak of unnormalisable states.

In measure-theoretic probability theory, given a probability space $(X,\Sigma)$ and a probability measure $d\mu$ (which you can pretend is $g(x) \, dx$ if you like), (defined so $\int_X \, d\mu=1$), an expected value (average) is always defined by
$$ \mathbb{E}_{\mu}[f(X)] = \int_X f(x) \, d\mu. $$
The other two are special cases of this, so really this is the only definition.

Comment: but the above example is not from quantum mechanics. Such that the square of the function f is not defined as a probability density as far as I see, it is just a Gaussian distribution. That is why I was wondering...